# The use of assumenosideeffects in ProGuard

Tags: proguard, android-proguard

I read from http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html about the use of `assumenosideeffects`. My question refers to the following paragraph:

> -assumenosideeffects class_specification
>       Specifies methods that don't have any side effects (other than maybe returning a value). In the optimization step, **ProGuard will
>   then remove calls to such methods, if it can determine that the return
>   values aren't used.** ProGuard will analyze your program code to find
>   such methods automatically. It will not analyze library code, for
>   which this option can therefore be useful. For example, you could
>   specify the method System.currentTimeMillis(), so that any idle calls
>   to it will be removed. With some care, you can also use the option to
>   remove logging code. Note that ProGuard applies the option to the
>   entire hierarchy of the specified methods. Only applicable when
>   optimizing. In general, making assumptions can be dangerous; you can
>   easily break the processed code. Only use this option if you know what
>   you're doing!

I would need to understand how does ProGuard determine "that the return values aren't used". In particular, if the method calls do not return any value, are they always removed?

Answer (score 11):

> if the method calls do not return any value, are they always removed?

The answer is Yes. An example is in Chromium [sources](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/init/ChromeBrowserInitializer.java?q=RemovableInRelease&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=107):

```
private ChromeBrowserInitializer(Context context) {
    mApplication = (ChromeApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    initLeakCanary();
}

@RemovableInRelease
private void initLeakCanary() {
    // Watch that Activity objects are not retained after their onDestroy() has been called.
    // This is a no-op in release builds.
    LeakCanary.install(mApplication);
}
```

Methods annotated with `@RemovableInRelease` will be removed from release builds. [chromium_code.flags](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/base/android/proguard/chromium_code.flags?q=RemovableInRelease&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=44):

```
# Remove methods annotated with this if their return value is unused.
-assumenosideeffects class ** {
@org.chromium.base.annotations.RemovableInRelease <methods>;
}
```